# The console does not show any printed output when a feature file is executed

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

i am trying to print the output written in the step definitions into eclipse console. but i do not see any output in the console

i have added these below dependencies into my project and i have also included "pretty" and monochrome :true in the runner class

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>sampleProject</groupId>
  <artifactId>sampleProject</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>sampleProject</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

    <build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </pluginManagement>
</build>

  <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>    
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.7.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>  
          <groupId>com.sun</groupId> 
           <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${java.home}\lib\tools-1.8.0.jar</systemPath>
     </dependency> 

    <dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.7.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

      <dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.7.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.cobertura</groupId>
    <artifactId>cobertura</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
    <version>4.8.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.6</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-jvm -->
     <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
        <version>4.7.1</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency> 

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.19</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>

      <dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-html</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit-dep -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-dep</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.14.3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>4.7.1</version>
    </dependency>


  </dependencies>
</project>
```

for example if i print any thing in my step definitions like
System.out.println("2+2");

when i ran this code,  only see the below lines in the console

```
 [RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.3
Starting ChromeDriver 76.0.3809.68 (420c9498db8ce8fcd190a954d51297672c1515d5-refs/branch-heads/3809@{#864}) on port 9315
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
Aug 02, 2019 11:54:35 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Feature: Check addition in Google calculatorcontent
   In order to verify that Google calculator work correctly
   As a user of Google
   I should be able to get correct addition result

  Scenario: Addition                     # src/main/java/Features/sample.feature:6
    Given I open Google                  # SampleStepDef.I_open_google()
    When I enter "2+2" in search textbox # SampleStepDef.I_enter_in_search_textbox(String)
    Then I should get result as "4"      # SampleStepDef.I_should_get_correct_result(String)
PASSED: runScenario("Addition", "Check addition in Google calculatorcontent")
        Runs Cucumber Scenarios

===============================================
```

the console does not display anything else other than this.

it also does not display the number of scenarios and steps passed or failed like

```
1 Scenarios ([33m1 undefined[0m)
   3 Steps ([33m3 undefined[0m)
   0m0.000s
```

And here is my tesRunner code
    package Runner;

```
import io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
import io.cucumber.testng.CucumberOptions;

@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/main/java/Features",
        glue = {"StepDefinitions"},
       // tags = "@SmokeTest",
        monochrome = true,
        dryRun = false,
        strict = true,
        plugin = {
                "pretty",
                "html:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber-pretty",
                "json:target/cucumber-reports/CucumberTestReport.json",
                "rerun:target/cucumber-reports/rerun.txt"
        }
        )

public class TestRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {


}
```

and stepDefifnition code

```
package StepDefinitions;


import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.testng.Assert;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;

import io.cucumber.java.After;
import io.cucumber.java.Before;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
import io.cucumber.java.en.When;
public class SampleStepDef {


    protected WebDriver driver;
     private static Logger Log = Logger.getLogger(Logger.class.getName());
     @Before
        public void setup() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Admin\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    @Given("^I open Google$")
    public void I_open_google() {
        //Set implicit wait of 10 seconds and launch google

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
    }

    @When("^I enter \"([^\"]*)\" in search textbox$")
    public void I_enter_in_search_textbox(String additionTerms) {
        //Write term in google textbox
        WebElement googleTextBox = driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfq"));
        googleTextBox.sendKeys(additionTerms);

        //Click on searchButton
        WebElement searchButton = driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfb"));
        searchButton.click();
    }

    @Then("^I should get result as \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void I_should_get_correct_result(String expectedResult) {
        //Get result from calculator
        WebElement calculatorTextBox = driver.findElement(By.id("cwos"));
        String result = calculatorTextBox.getText();

        //Verify that result of 2+2 is 4
        Assert.assertEquals(result, expectedResult);

        driver.close();
    }

     @After
        public void closeBrowser() {
            driver.quit();
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it opening the google chrome browser?.
I think your code is not reaching to the point where there are print statements, Please share your test runner and step-definition file.

Comment: thanks for your reply Nitish. Yes, when i execute the code , it is launching google chrome browser and running the test cases. But, the console will display only if test cases are passed or failed and nothing else.

Comment: @KunalDeepReddy Deep Reddy I did little debugging on your problem and found out below.
I changed the version of all the maven dependancies from 4.7.1 to 4.2.2 and used cucumber.api for importing classes and executed the testrunner.
output shows the scenarios and steps passed/failed
and when I changed the version back to 4.7.1(as io.cucumber package is present in this) and import classes from io.cucumber
output does not show the scenarios and steps pass/failed.

Comment: @KunalDeepReddy Also , with your current setup If you run your feature file directly as "Run as feature" then it shows the desired output.
as for your other problem , I put system.out.println and it printed the output in console for me irrespective of above issue.:)
I believe this has to do with the latest cucumber version 2.2.0 introduced under new dependancy io.cucumber. 
You might want to check the github project and put this query over there

Comment: thanks a lot nitish , I have changed the version of maven dependencies from 4.7.1 to 4.3.0. now it is working fine.

Comment: @KunalDeepReddy. Glad it helped you.

Comment: Which means in the latest version the steps are not displayed in the console level?

Answer (score 1):

With cucumber-jvm 4.5.0 and up, in order to see the summary statistics at the end of a run you need to explicit ask for it via the plugins you define in your runner class. If you add the "summary" (as you have already "pretty") you should be able to see again the totals of Scenarios/Steps and time it took.
This has changed via https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/pull/1670